# R - how to plot graphic to an exists window that created by another application

Tags: r, window, output

I wrote a Windows application in c++, i want to do data analysis in R but output the graphic to the window of my application, so i call a R routine within my application and i can send the handle of the window to R routine, but i do not know how to set the window as device of R's graphics.

the **dev {grDevices}** functions provide control over multiple graphics devices, but i think **dev.set()** or **windows()** did not work at this situation, what should i do ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should implement a hook that redirects R graph to your application Window. I have not done it in c++ as the application, but the c# code to do it essentially is standard windows API.

It draws on hook code written by Dino Esposito around 2004.

http://rdotnet.codeplex.com/workitem/7

Comment: thank you sir! that is greet, but there are something wrong in the demo, but does not matter i will do it with c++.

Comment: Yes, there is a version problem, because 1.5 is slightly different. However, the core part you are interested in is not affected.